# Getting a 'variable not in scope' error when a package is clearly imported

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a simple program:

```hs
module Foo where

import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Data.Functor

main :: IO ()
main = void $ runMaybeT $ do
  x <- hoistMaybe (Just 5) :: MaybeT IO Int -- Compile error on this line
  pure ()
```

I got an error on the line using `hoistMaybe` saying

```
    Variable not in scope:
      hoistMaybe :: Maybe Int -> MaybeT IO Int
```

This `hoistMaybe` is clearly present in the `transformers` package under the `Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe` module: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#v:hoistMaybe

My Cabal file also listed `transformers` as a dependency:

```yaml
cabal-version: 3.0
build-depends: base
             , transformers
```

What do I need to do to make `hoistMaybe` in scope for me to call?

---

My environment if it helps nail down the issue:

```
Hardware: Apple MacBook Pro M1 Arm64
OS: MacOS 13.1 Ventura
Compiler toolchain
  - GHCUp v0.1.18.0
  - GHC v9.4.2
  - Cabal v3.8.1.0
```

Comment: I would check that the version of `transformers` you depend on matches the documentation you're reading. Also, instead of importing the whole module, import the specific function you want. This way GHC will know where you intended `hoistMaybe` to come from, and it can issue a more helpful error message.

Comment: @amalloy is there a way to check the exact version of `transformers` my current project is referencing?

Comment: If you look at [the changelog for `transformers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/changelog), you'll see that `hoistMaybe` was added in `0.6.0.0`. You should constrain your Cabal dependency on `transformers` to have this minimum version - I believe Cabal will then pull in the correct dependency version automatically, if it can find it.